# Watchdog Big Brother Watching - what's this?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I would like to know what's this:

> W/Watchdog( 1396): Watchdog Big Brother Watching : com.android.server.WindowManagerService

I received this message in logcat when I connected LG P970 to PC.

Comment: what is issue with that!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Log of the watch dog timer of windowManagerService. 
watch dog concept is usually used to check if the system is not blocking , why would you worry about it !

Comment: Because of "Big Brother Watching"...

Comment: Don't worry about it, its just a joke , just like Log.wtf